# Ruby On Rails Devise: How can I avoid email uniqueness validation during sign up and rewrite to check if it's unique only if has role "X"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, registration, validates-uniqueness-of

I want to interrupt the default registration action in my rails application, changing email validation. All I need is to have email field unique ONLY if that user is already registered AND has role `'X'`.

I've tried the following but my application returns `"Email has already been taken"` message:

validation:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, {allow_blank: true, if: :already_exists_as_x?}

def already_exists_as_x?
  User.where(email: self.email, role: :X).exists?
end
```

(I will be glad for any help)

Comment: By removing it you might end up having two users with the same email address with different roles, which is not a good idea...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your model includes :validatable module of Devise, you can remove this module from your model and write your own validations as you desire.

In your model (say user.rb) your devise call contains :validatable like:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable, :trackable
```

Remove or comment :validatable from this call, then your own validations should work as you expected.

Comment: Thank You for reply .
I've removed :validatable, then do validation like this: 

validates :email, {unique: true, if: :already_exists_as_vg? , on: :create}

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: it looks right, you may try to overwrite Devise's validation methods as another way. see: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb

Comment: Thank You a lot.
I found another way to implement the whole logic. Btw what you told was properly solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 5, you need to override the below method in your User model

```
  def will_save_change_to_email?
    if User.where(email: self.email, role: :X).exists?
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

when you return `true`, devise will go ahead and apply the `uniqueness` check and when you return `false` devise will not check for uniqueness

You will also need to remove the `unique index` as by passing devise validation alone will not let you save the user

```
  def change
    remove_index :users, :name => :index_users_on_email
  end
```

**Note:** once you remove the index and create records with duplicate email ids, you will not be able to add the unique index back again at a later moment as creating unique index will fail